# How to drop a unique constraint in Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE "VACCINE" 
(
  "CVX"  INTEGER,
  "CPT"  CHAR(5),
  "SHORTNAME"  VARCHAR(20),
  "FULLNAME"  VARCHAR(256),
  "VTYPE"  CHAR(1),
 UNIQUE ("CVX")
);
```

but it turns out that CVX is not unique after all.  How do I drop the unique constraint?

I can get the name of the constraint like this

```
select rdb$constraint_name from rdb$relation_constraints where rdb$relation_name = 'VACCINE'
```

but I get a syntax error after I do this

```
alter table vaccine drop constraint 'INTEG_400'
```

where INTEG_400 is the result of the select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will work :

```
alter table vaccine drop constraint INTEG_400
```

Try with [IBExpert](http://www.ibexpert.com) : it will show you the code